# Patterns for implementing common class behavior through a class hierarchy

Tags: java, static

I have a Java class hierarchy for which a sub-tree of the hierarchy implements the same static data and methods.  I cannot inherit because they are all statics, but it smells to me when I am cutting and pasting the same bits of code from one class to the next.  One thing I am considering is to put the common bits in a class, and then give each of the sub-classes a static instance of that class.  Anyone have a thought about a better approach to this situation (without using generics)?

Comment: sure, avoid using static :-)

Comment: Java inheritance is really all about functions. Define an interface with one method per static value.  Implement and inherit it as needed.

Comment: are they private static? just curious

Answer (score 0):

That's sounds about right. Just have a class of statics that are immutable and reference them directly in the classes that need it (call is Constants or something like that. You shouldn't need to create an instance to refer to static objects on a class though - they're static so they "should just exist".

i.e.

```
     public class MyConstants{
            public static final String MyConstantValue1 = "Billy";
            public static final String MyConstantValue2 = "Sally";
        }

     public class SomeClass{
        public void something(){
            System.out.println(MyConstants.MyConstantValue1);    
        } 
    }

    public class SomeSubClass extends SomeClass{
        @override
        public void something(){
            System.out.println(MyConstants.MyConstantValue2);    
        }
    }
```

Comment: Not on point - perhaps I was not specific enough.  The static data is distinct for each class in the hierarchy.

Comment: @LunkerBuster Is the data static or is it not? Static methods and data can just be tossed into a class on the side. If it is instance data, i.e. data that is in the object itself and can only be shared by methods or by making it public on the class, then it isn't static data.

Comment: The data is static, but different for each class in the hierarchy; but the same for all instances of that class.

Comment: @LunkerBuster I updated my answer with some more details. I feel that a class of statics outside of the class hierarchy is the best way to do it because the most you can do in inheritance with static members is hide data (i.e. use private) but that doesn't help much since the data cannot be overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

My solution 
I have created a separate class which implements the functionality which is troubling me.
I give every class in the hierarchy their own static instance.  Works a treat.